# Puppet & Docker

Tags: docker, chef-infra, puppet, configuration-management

I was going through Puppet and comparing it with Docker.

I came to know that Puppet is used for configuration management for scalable infrastructure. New VM's setup can be done with same configuration easily etc.

Seems that Docker is also capable of all these though in a different way.

Is docker replacing the configuration management tools like puppet, chef etc?

Please help me to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. We don't allow these kinds of questions as they don't have a specific "correct" answer and so aren't a good fit for our Q&A style here. I would recommend asking on on the DevOps public Slack teams (hangops, DevOpsChef), a local meetup group, or a mailing list of one of the related projects.

Comment: Puppet and Docker serve very different purposes, with little overlap.  They aren't really comparable to each other, nor are they mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure of if this question belongs here or not, but never the less, here is some source material that probable explains it better than me: http://cloudify.co/2014/10/30/Docker-cloud-orchestration-configuration-management.html

Docker operates in a different manner than Chef or Puppet. Docker is (with limited exceptions) a static system. Chef et. al. are dynamic in nature. If you seek to change a fleet of Docker provisioned services you would create a new Docker container, push it out and blow away your old ones.

Chef et. al. instead check frequently for state changes and when they occur they pull those changes down and converge. This leaves room for having parts of the server automated and some not (if its a difficult to manage portion, for instance, or for emergency repairs).

Of the two Docker is the stronger model in my opinion but even then you should have some well defined CM to create your docker images, such as serverless Chef, Ansible or other.